# How do you use regular expressions with the cp command in Linux?

Tags: linux, cp

I am attempting to only copy a subset of files from one directory to another using `cp` however am greeted with the message `cp: cannot stat [^\.php]': No such file or directory`. Is there a way to use regular expressions only using the `cp` command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No.**

The `cp` command does not possess the capability to process any of its arguments as regular expressions. Even wildcards are not handled by it (or most executables); rather they are handled by the shell.

`cp test/* test2/` is actually expanded by bash, and all that `cp` really sees for its arguments are `cp test/file1 test/file2 test/file3 test2/` (or whatever is appropriate based upon the actual contents of `test/`).

Also, I don't think your expression, `[^\.php]`, will match what you want it to (it doesn't match only files that contain `.php`).

You probably want to look into the `find` utility to filter out a list of files based upon regular expression, and then use `xargs` to apply the returned file list to the `cp` command (presuming find doesn't have a built-in handler for copying files; I'm not intimately familiar with the tool).

You might try:

```
find . ! -iregex ".*\.php.*" -exec cp {} /destination/folder/ \;
```

This says to search the current directory recursively for files which do not contain ".php" in the path and copy them into `/destination/folder/`.

As requested, a more specifc breakdown of the arguments:

- `.` - Location to start the search - in this case, the current directory
- `!` - "Not" operator, invert the result of the next test
- `-iregex` - Case-insensitive regular expression test. Next argument is the expression.
- `".*\.php.*"` - Regular expression matching `<Anything>.php<Anything>` - Any file that has ".php" somewhere in the path. (Note, including being inside a folder which contains ".php" in the name, you'd need a more complex expression to match only the files)
- `-exec` - Execute a command if the preceding tests return true. Next argument is the command, all remaining arguments up to `;` are passed to the command. the `{}` is a special argument representing the filename.
- `cp` - The command that find` should run on each of the matched path names.
- `{}` - The path to the file that was found, passed to `cp` as an argument so that it knows what file to copy
- `/destination/folder/` - argument passed to `cp`, telling `cp` where it should copy the file to.
- `\;` - This is the `;` terminator that `-exec` is looking for. We escape it with a `\` so that your shell doesn't try to parse it and instead feeds it as an argument to the command (`find`)

It's rather difficult to write a regular expression which matches "strings that do not have `.php`", so we instead tell `find` to search for strings that *do* contain `.php` and then invert the results with `!`.

Comment: `find . -name [^\.php] -exec cp {} /path/to/location \;` be careful for files with special characters.

Comment: @Darth Android - Thanks. I wasn't aware that `cp` and other binaries were not able to expand regular expressions. Would you mind elaborating what each of the options and arguments mean in the sample example you gave? I know that `.` refers to the the current directory but what do `!`, `{}`, `\;`, etc refer to as well what they mean? For example why do you have to escape the `;`?

Comment: @Rob - What do you mean by special files?

Comment: @Rob - I attempted a similar expression to remove specific files however it ended up deleting all files in the directory. My command was `find . -name '[^\.txt]' -exec rm {} \;` hence my reluctance to use `find`. Probably a mistake on my part but am unsure what I did wrong. As far as my understanding `{}` refers to each file found by the command `find . -name '[^\.txt]'`

Comment: What are you trying to match with the regex?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey explained what each of the arguments do. The issue is `[^\.txt]` doesn't match what you think it does. It matches "Any one character that is `^` OR `\ ` OR `.` OR `t` OR `x` OR `t`", which combined with `-name` will match any file that has any one of those characters somewhere in the name (most will have a `.` if they have an extension) - This is probably why your files got deleted.

Answer (score 11):

You may use few other tools from console, like grep and xargs.

```
ls -1 some_folder | egrep 'some_extended_regex' | xargs cp -t destination_folder
```

Comment: How is `{}` different to that of `-t`?

Comment: Not much in this case. Alternate syntax for xargs would be 'xargs cp {} destination_folder'.

standard cp syntax takes one or many sources and one destination in the end, when you use -t option, you can specify the destination after the -t, then use the rest of the line for sources. I just find  the -t option more convenient in this case.
In the other example the {} is replaced by what is piped to xargs (stdin), in this case the filename.

Comment: This approach assumes certain limitations on the filenames used, e.g. no newlines.

Answer (score 0):

To copy 100 log files into another log2 folder of same directory, I use following

***cp app.log.[0-9][0-9] log2***

Answer (score -1):

You can run following command easy to use:

```
find /home/usr/search_dir -iname *file_name_portion*.txt | xargs cp -t /home/usr/destination_folder
```

cool haa!!

Comment: Does not use regular expressions.